# Existence and continuity of partial derivatives implies differentiability, proof?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

here's my problem: attending Calculus II class I ran into this proof that is not clear to me (our teacher takes so many things as obvious when they're actually not).

**Theorem:** Let $f:D\subset\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that it admits all partial derivatives and they're continuous around a point $x_0 \in D$ then $f$ is differentiable in $x_0$.

**Proof:** ( My attempt, cause at half of it, my teacher chokes it saying that a thing it implies differentiability ):

We're showing this in the specific case $n=2$, where $\vec{x_0} = (x,y)$ and $\vec{h} = (h_x, h_y)$.

The following identity is valid (we add and subtract $f(x,y+h_y)$ ):

$f(x+h_x, y+h_y) - f(x,y) = f(x+h_x, y+h_y) - f(x,y+h_y) + f(x,y+h_y) - f(x,y)$

We can recognize here that

$f(x+h_x, y+h_y) - f(x,y+h_y) = h_x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y+h_x) + o(h_x)$

and similarly

$f(x,y+h_y) - f(x,y) = h_y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) + o(h_y)$

It follows that

$f(x+h_x, y+h_y) - f(x,y) = h_x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y+h_x) + o(h_x) + h_y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) + o(h_y)$

Adding and subtracting from the RHS $h_x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ we get

$f(x+h_x, y+h_y) - f(x,y) = h_x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y+h_x) -h_x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) + h_x\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) + h_y\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) + o(h_x) + o(h_y)$

Which is equivalent to this:

$ f(x+h_x, y+h_y) - f(x,y) = h_x[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y+h_x) -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)] + \nabla f|_{(x,y)}\cdot h + o(h_x) + o(h_y)$

By definiton of differential:

$ f(x+h_x, y+h_y) - f(x,y) = h_x[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y+h_x) -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)] + df(x,y) + o(h_x) + o(h_y)$

Here $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y+h_x) -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ goes to $0$ for small enough $h_x$ and then, being the partial derivative continuous, this whole thing goes to $0$ (**I'm not really sure about this, can I say it even without passing through the limit?**).

Then from the previous we have that $ f(x+h_x, y+h_y) - f(x,y) = df(x,y) + o(h_x) + o(h_y)$ which allows us to assert that the hypothesis is true.

**This too is not clear at all to me: Somehow $o(h_x) + o(h_y) \to o(\begin{Vmatrix}\vec{h}\end{Vmatrix})$? Why?**

Comment: $o(h_x)/\|h\|=(o(h_x)/|h_x|)/\|h/|h_x|\|$. Observe that $\|h/|h_x|\|$ is bounded away from $0$ (since it is $\sqrt{1+\text{ non-negative terms}}$), and $o(h_x)/|h_x|\to 0$. Therefore $o(h_x)\subset o(h)$.

Comment: The part $h_x\left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y+h_x)-\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)\right]$ can just be swallowed by $o(h_x)$.

Comment: Well, typo there. It should have been $o(h_x)\subset o(\|h\|)$. The definition of $o(\|h\|)$ are functions that when divided by $\|h\|$ and letting $h\to0$, they tend to zero. We just took any function from $o(h_x)$, which I was still denoting as the whole set $o(h_x)$, divided it by $\|h\|$ and showed that it tended to zero (because after a little transformation the numerator tended to zero and the denominator was bounded away from zero).

Comment: @noodlesGroup: How do I show $h_x[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y+h_x) -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)]$ that is an higher order of infinitesimal than $h_x$?

PS: I deleted my previous comment cause I realized after all.

Comment: The same idea. Dividing by $h_x$ you are left with the stuff inside the brackets. Now let $h_x\to0$ and use continuity of the derivative.

Comment: It's funny how I just realize every time after typing. Thanks for your help

Comment: Some things in math are just symbol crunching. Often times it happens that when you write down the symbols, you see what crunching to do.

Comment: True story! Many times when I'm typing the question I think about how silly I was and close the window